# Remove Radio button Class if Parent div.class found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

want to remove radio button class **false** if parent div class s1 found.

```
<div class="s1">
<span>
<input name="question0" checked type="radio" value="C" class="false">
</span>
</div>
```

my script

```
$('.s1:has(input:radio:checked)').removeClass('false');
```

Comment: Have you got a specific reason, I'm only saying because in CSS you could target the selector  .s1 && .false to render differently if that's what your after.  IOW: if you had a class .false you can make it render different than if it had a parent with a class .s1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple selector, nothing special is required.

```
$('.s1 :radio').removeClass('false');
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.s1 :radio').removeClass('false');
});
```

```css
.false {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s1">
  <span>
<input name="question0" checked type="radio" value="C" class="false">
</span>
</div>
<div class="s2">
  <span>
<input name="question0" checked type="radio" value="C" class="false">
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this for just radio whether checked or not

```
$(".s1 input[type='radio']").removeClass('false');
```

And this one for only checked radio

```
$(".s1 input[type='radio']:checked").removeClass('false');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason is to alter the way the radio buttons looks, using jQuery is not really the normal way.

Here is an example without using jQuery, it's just been targeted in CSS instead.

```css
.s2 .false {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="s1">
  <input name="question0" 
         checked type="radio" 
         value="C" 
         class="false">  
</div>
<div class="s2">
  <input name="question0" 
         checked 
         type="radio" 
         value="C" 
         class="false">
</div>
```